# Setting up new cassandra cluster using snapshots?

Tags: cassandra

So, I have an existing 3 node cluster setup in cassandra which is hosted in X region in AWS. I have setup a cron job which takes snapshot of the existing cluster(all keyspaces) and uploads it to s3. So now if I have to setup a new cluster in Y region and populate the cluster via the snapshots from S3, how do I proceed? I have read the official documents from [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html) but I am worried that I'll lose data. I am confused in Step 7 and Step 8. Can someone please help me with a simplified approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are having the right info([link)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html) If you are worried with the given procedure in the link you can rebuild the new cluster from the first cluster.  Doing manual steps can be risky. Also scaling the new cluster with initial_token defined will be very difficult. So safest option is rebuild the datacenter from old datacenter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I would like to automate the script so that whenever I want to restore using the snapshots I can just run the script and the snapshots are then easily used to setup the new cluster. Can you please provide me any site articles/documents which might help me with this? I came across medusa but again I couldn't find much information about it and while it looks like it'll certainly make the tasks easier, their github is having a lot of open issues raised. Thanks!

Comment: It should not be always the case that you want to create a new cluster using the backups. It can be the case in situations like catastrophe. Otherwise in planned activity, rebuilding the cluster is the best option in my opinion. I am not aware of any such resource which you require. Probably you can put your query on slack channel of cassandra-medusa, there you can get replies from the developers and users.